# Add new text in text select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-select2

how to add new text in text select2
from

```
<select class=user>
<option value=1>John Doe</option>
<option value=2>Jane Doe</option> 
</select>
```

to

```
<select class=user>
<option value=1>John Doe - verified</option>
<option value=2>Jane Doe-verified</option>
</select>
```

i triy to add custom text after current text in option.  I am new in select2 and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope help you!

```
<script> 
$(function () {
    $(".user option").each(function () {
        let val = $(this).text();
        let text = "- verified";
        let str_join = val + text;
        $(this).html(str_join);
    })
})
```